# JavaFX Stretch Canvas To Dimensions

Tags: java, javafx, canvas, rendering

In my C++ Windows programs I draw directly to a fixed pixel buffer (`u32 *`) and stretch it to fit the window dimensions:

```
StretchDIBits(device_context, 
              0, 0, window_width, window_height,
              src_x, src_y, src_width, src_height,
              src_memory, src_info,
              DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
```

I'm new to JavaFX.
In JavaFX say I have:

```
@Override
public void
start(Stage primary_stage) throws Exception
{
   Group root = new Group();
   Scene scene = new Scene(root);
   primary_stage.setScene(scene);
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(1280, 720);
   root.getChildren().add(canvas);
   GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
}
```

I want to treat the canvas (it's `GraphicsContext`) as the fixed sized pixel buffer in my Windows example. Each frame I want to stretch or shrink it to the window dimensions (or whatever dimensions I specify). Many examples I have seen seem to increase the width and height of the canvas node itself. I want to stretch the *content* of the canvas, not the canvas node itself if that makes sense.

Is there an equivalent to `StretchDIBits` for JavaFX?

Comment: @Slaw If I take `scale_x = canvas_fixed_width / window_width` how would I get the current window width?

Comment: But does that make sense? Any graphics in the canvas would just look distorted. Is that what you want?

Comment: @mipa I know without handling aspect ratio it will look distorted (fine for debugging) If JavaFX has the equivalent function I'm looking for (which is common in graphics libraries, e.g. Windows API, Xlib, AppKit) then handling the aspect ratio is straightforward.

Comment: @Slaw My loop in a `AnimationTimer` `handle()` calls `gc.scale(1280 / scene.getWidth(), 720 / scene.getHeight());` This works initial open, but goes haywire when resizing. I tried setting on `canvas` but it pushes content inward when increasing i.e. 0,0 is moved to center and zooms in when shrunk

Comment: You should ask yourself if the Canvas is the right approach at all. To me it sounds as if the scene graph would be the better option. One should not always look for one-to-one replacements of concepts between different environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a built-in method you can call to do what you want. But you can scale the `Canvas` to fill the available space. You'll need to continually update the scale factor as the canvas's parent resizes. This is probably best implemented via a custom layout. For example:

```java
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;

public class AutoScalingCanvas extends Region {

  private final Canvas canvas;

  public AutoScalingCanvas(double canvasWidth, double canvasHeight) {
    this.canvas = new Canvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    getChildren().add(canvas);
  }

  public GraphicsContext getGraphicsContext2D() {
    return canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
  }

  @Override
  protected void layoutChildren() {
    double x = getInsets().getLeft();
    double y = getInsets().getTop();
    double w = getWidth() - getInsets().getRight() - x;
    double h = getHeight() - getInsets().getBottom() - y;

    // preserve aspect ratio while also staying within the available space
    double sf = Math.min(w / canvas.getWidth(), h / canvas.getHeight());
    canvas.setScaleX(sf);
    canvas.setScaleY(sf);

    positionInArea(canvas, x, y, w, h, -1, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
  }
}
```

And here's an example using the above:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    AutoScalingCanvas canvas = new AutoScalingCanvas(500, 300);
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillOval(200, 100, 100, 100);
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setLineWidth(5);
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setStroke(Color.RED);
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().strokeRect(0, 0, 500, 300);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(canvas));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to cause blurry text when maximized?

Comment: That doesn't surprise me, but I don't know how to fix it.